# 'import ase' does not load submodule 'ase.io'

Tags: python, import, module, ase

I experienced a problem using the 'import module' instead of the 'from module import ...' syntax. This clearly shows that my understanding of loading modules is not sufficient. As far as I find elsewhere, this difference is mainly a style issue, but this does not explains the following situation.

I installed ase using

```
sudo apt install python3-ase
```

I tried the following:

```
import ase
ase.io.read
```

which outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'ase' has no attribute 'io'
```

However, when trying

```
from ase.io import read
read
```

or - also possible -

```
from ase.io import read
import ase
ase.io.read
```

I get the output

```
<function read at 0x7f33dc721730>
```

The latter is the desired result as I want to use the ase.io.read function to read a .cif file.

More about the origin of the problem is shown in the following python session:

```
import sys
import ase
sys.modules['ase']
```

module 'ase' from '/home/vanbeverj/Programs/anaconda3/envs/abienv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ase/**init**.py'

```
dir(ase)
```

['Atom', 'Atoms', 'LooseVersion', '**all**', '**builtins**', '**cached**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**', '**path**', '**spec**', '**version**', 'ase', 'atom', 'atoms', 'calculators', 'cell', 'constraints', 'data', 'dft', 'formula', 'geometry', 'np', 'parallel', 'symbols', 'sys', 'transport', 'units', 'utils']

```
from ase.io import read
dir(ase)
```

['Atom', 'Atoms', 'LooseVersion', '**all**', '**builtins**', '**cached**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**', '**path**', '**spec**', '**version**', 'ase', 'atom', 'atoms', 'calculators', 'cell', 'constraints', 'data', 'dft', 'formula', 'geometry', 'io', 'np', 'parallel', 'symbols', 'sys', 'transport', 'units', 'utils']

The 'dir(ase)' commands have clearly different outputs. What happens with e.g. the io submodule? Can someone explains me what is going on under the hood?

Answer (score 2):

It's up to each package whether to expose an imported submodule as an attribute, or whether to import the submodule at all.

`os`, for example, does import and expose `os.path`.

In your case, `ase` does *not* expose the `io` submodule as an attribute of `ase`. (Whether `io` was imported is another matter; you could check `sys.modules`.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it seems like `tkinter`.
In `tkinter`,if we want to use `ttk`,we must use

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
```

if we use

```
import tkinter

.......
btn = tkinter.ttk.Button(xxxxxx)
```

Then it will show `AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'ttk'`.

You can see the `ase` module source.In ase > `__init__.py` file,`import ase` means that import all of class or function in `__init__.py`.

`from ase import io`,maybe it means that it will import the `io` module(io is a independent .py file) in ase folder